# Найти количество слов в строке между двумя символами в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно посчитать количество слов в строке между двумя символами ";". Похожий код на плюсах у меня работает, а вот на пайтоне нет. Пишет что значение k не в диапазоне значений(если k будет равно i то пишет что количество слов = 0). Как можно это исправить?

```
s="hello; hi bbbb aaaaa dfdfdf dfdvdv; bye"
count = 0
slovo=0
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i]==";":
        k=i+1
        while s[k]!=";":
            if s[k]!=" "and slovo==0:
                slovo=1
                count+=1
            elif s[k]==" ":
                slovo=0
            k+=1
print("Kolvo slov:   ",count)
```

Comment: у вас есть ограничение на использование функций? два split решают задачу сильно проще

Comment: ограничений нет, но я ещё не знакома с этой функцией. Как её использовать в этой задаче?

Comment: `len(s.split(';')[1].split())`

Comment: огромное Вам спасибо)

Answer (score -1):

эммм как насчёт самого простого варианта:

```
str='...'
sep='...'

count=False
counter=0

for it in str:
  if it==sep:
    count=True if not count else False
  if count:
     counter+=1
```

не описаны проблеммы вхождения трёх и более сепараторов, так как нет условий их обработки

Comment: 1) не называйте переменные именами встроенных типов 2) а что вы считаете? 3) весь ваш `count = ...` - это `count = not count`

Comment: @splash58 внимательнее будте ```str='aaaBccccBdddd'
sep='B'

count=False
counter=0

for it in str:
  if it==sep:
    count=True if not count else False
  if count:
     counter+=1

print(counter)``` возвращает 5 учитывая один разделитель

Comment: str='aaaBcccc aaa dddBdddd' - тоже 1 ? надо же

Comment: ```str='aaaBcccc aaa dddBdddd' ``` 13, вы какую версию питона используете?

Comment: а если if сдвинуть - 13. что тоже не соответствует количеству слов

Comment: чел, что за хрень ты несёшь? if сдвинуть? в питоне важна табуляция

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132521/discussion-between-ganz-and-splash58).